# Angular 2 animate property base on value of other property

Tags: angular

I know you can animate a property based on its runtime value. E.g. this example from the Angular 2 GUIDE:

```
animations: [
  trigger('shrinkOut', [
    state('in', style({height: '*'})),
    transition('* => void', [
      style({height: '*'}),
      animate(250, style({height: 0}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

But is it possible to animate a property base on the runtime value of another property? E.g. I want to animate the margin-left from 0px to the current width.

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyOutLeft', [
    state('in', style({margin-left: '0px'})),
    transition('* => void', [
      style({margin-left: '0px'}),
      animate(250, style({margin-left: '-width'}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

> E.g. I want to animate the margin-left from 0px to the current width.

That can be done by transform: translateX(-100%), since the percentage refers to the current width. And it's smoother than animating margin-left anyway.